# How are Java POJO tests getting executed without a test framework?

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin

I am working on a Java 11 application, and I have the following POJO test.

```java
public class HelloWorldTest {

    public void testGetHello() {

        assert("Hello World!".equals(HelloWorld.getHello()));
    }
}
```

Below is the pom.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run "mvn test" in IntelliJ Terminal, the HelloWorldTest gets picked up and executed.

What is happening under the hood? I understand that as I am using Maven, Surefire plugin gets pulled it, but what test runner is Surefire plugin using to pick up and execute the HelloWorldTest?

Comment: `run mvn test -X` and you get detailed informations

Answer (score 3):

Everything in the POJO tests is based on the [Java reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/pojo-test.html

> POJO tests look very much like JUnit or TestNG tests, though they do not require dependencies on these artifacts. A test class should be named `**/*Test` and should contain `test*` methods which will each be executed by Surefire.

> Validating assertions can be done using the JDK 1.4 assert keyword.

> Fixtures can be setup before and after each `test*` method by implementing a set-up and a tear-down methods. These methods must match the following signatures to be recognized and executed before and after each test method:
> `public void setUp();`
> `public void tearDown();`

Surefire uses **test providers**, each of them is an implementation of [Maven Surefire Provider API](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/api.html).
The provider implementations are found using the [standard Java ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism:

```java
private Set<String> getManuallyConfiguredProviders() {
    ...
    return serviceLoader.lookup(SurefireProvider.class, cl);
    ...
}
```

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html

> Which providers are available is controlled simply by the inclusion of the appropriate dependencies (JUnit4, JUnit5 and TestNG).

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html

> You can also specify multiple providers as dependencies, and they will all be run and produce a common report. This may be especially handy with external providers, since there are few use cases for combining the included providers.

If you download the [Surefire source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire), you can see that there are some "well-known surefire providers":

```java
protected List<ProviderInfo> createProviders(TestClassPath testClasspath) throws MojoExecutionException {
    Artifact junitDepArtifact = getJunitDepArtifact();
    return providerDetector.resolve(
            new DynamicProviderInfo(null),
            new JUnitPlatformProviderInfo(getJUnitPlatformRunnerArtifact(), getJUnit5Artifact(), testClasspath),
            new TestNgProviderInfo(getTestNgArtifact()),
            new JUnitCoreProviderInfo(getJunitArtifact(), junitDepArtifact),
            new JUnit4ProviderInfo(getJunitArtifact(), junitDepArtifact),
            new JUnit3ProviderInfo());
    }
```

Since the JUnit3 tests were based purely on reflection, it is the [JUnit3Provider](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/surefire-providers/surefire-junit3/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junit/JUnit3Provider.java) which runs the POJO tests, because it uses exactly the same method to identify the tests within the source code.

```java
public JUnit3Provider(ProviderParameters booterParameters) {
    ...
    testChecker = new PojoAndJUnit3Checker(jUnit3TestChecker);
}
```

Your question about which **test runner** is used does not make sense in the case of the POJO tests, as *test runner* is a term from JUnit and TestNG, and not from Surefire.

Comment: My specific question is what test runner will Surefire use to pick up and execute the POJOs if I don't specify any test frameworks like TestNG or JUnit